# Translation: "so" to begin a sentence

Tags: traducción, modismos

So in English I often start sentences with the word '*so*'. Often I do this when beginning an explanation, but there are heaps of other uses too, like when telling a story or when expecting an answer from somebody.

An example I just read was:

> '*So* a friend of mine...'

Other uses are

> So, how is your report going?
>
> So the way it works is...

Are there similar ways of expressing this in Spanish? I understand there might not be an equivalent in Spanish but is there anything similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*So*, in this context... Pardon, let me start again...

So, *so*, in this context, is known as a [discourse marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker) (see [relevant English L&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43273/9983)), of which there are many others, including (from wikipedia) *you know*, *actually*, *basically*, *like*, *I mean*, and *okay*. The description of discourse markers taken from wikipedia reads:

> In linguistics, a discourse marker is a word or phrase that is relatively syntax-independent and does not change the meaning of the sentence, and has a somewhat empty meaning.

In your first example, the word *so* can be replaced with any of these with the same grammatical construct resulting, and little or no change in meaning.

Spanish also has this concept, known as [marcadores de discurso](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcadores_del_discurso). Some common ones in Spanish (agian taken from wikipedia) are: *pues*, *pues bien*, *así las cosas*, and *dicho esto/eso*.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the way you use *so*, you have different choices in Spanish.

In this case:

> So a friend of mine
>
> Resulta que...
>
> Resulta que un amigo... / Pues resulta que un amigo...

And in this one:

> So the way it works...
>
> Así que la forma en que funciona... / Pues la forma en que funciona...